# why is my website not deploying on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have been learning rails for about a month and I have created my first simple static website using ruby on rails. it functions well on `localhost:3000`.

I have pushed all the files onto GitHub and have followed several Youtube videos on how to deploy the site using GitHub and heroku. I have used them to work through several errors I got and finally managed to "deploy" the site.

However, all I get is a kind of welcome page that says it is my site. it is just a single page with nothing but "Heroku. Welcome to your new app." Written on it. What is the final stage I am missing? why am I not seeing my website?

Below are the application logs:

```
2017-03-22T20:20:58.057644+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user *******@******.com

2017-03-22T20:20:58.063330+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user *******@******.com

2017-03-22T20:20:58.189041+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user *******@******.com

2017-03-22T20:31:55.915631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=d69fedea-d149-4836-b349-aa490c3b9654 fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-22T20:31:56.290278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=0c5752c0-b960-443e-8f07-0c2346055ff9 fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-24T18:44:37.424270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=62e3ddce-34e5-4fb2-892b-2ae9cf5ca93d fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-24T18:44:37.811237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=7a5b7d99-1b83-406d-bdc2-c68c3d5efa33 fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-24T18:44:55.237261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=4057726f-e2b9-464b-a970-b37306051e63 fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-25T20:29:38.837541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=47282fae-e30f-43d1-be52-808c956cad7b fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-25T21:10:30.120292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=94863f09-962f-49d5-90db-c0fbf7ac0c8a fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2017-03-26T11:07:07.914421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=vast-shelf-39597.herokuapp.com request_id=c3fac4f9-8786-493c-a859-05690842ca89 fwd="88.11.201.253" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my routes file: I think there is something missing with "root", no?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'handm/home'
  get 'handm/about'
  get 'handm/contact'
  get 'handm/industries'
  get 'handm/languages'
  get 'handm/services'
```

Comment: Can you send the a screenshot of your deployment and your heroku app name

Comment: Also post your Heroku logs (go to your app an click on view  logs).

Comment: I had this happen because my app was not in the root of the git repo I pushed to heroku

Comment: You set the root in your routes file right?

Comment: see edit for application logs and screenshot of the deployment of the app

Comment: I am not sure if I set the root file right.  what should it be set to. this could be the cause?

Comment: @Rockwell Rice - see routes file, is this correct?. thanks for your help

Comment: @maxple -  how did you resolve the issue with the routes file?

Comment: @Mohamed Sami - see screenshot added

Comment: @Gerry - log file added.

Comment: Yes, the root was the issue. I thought of that at beginning but when you said it worked fine in your local environment, I excluded this assumption

Comment: @Mohamed Sami. now only the home page works though. the other pages "do not exist" according to the error message.

Comment: make the following to routes.rb     root :to=> "handm#home" and then resources : handm try this and tell me if it solved your issue

Comment: also, run rake routes and make sure that you have all routes defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the deploy is fine.

You have to set the "root" route of your application. The root route is the route it will go to when a user first visits you app.

I am assuming home is the route you want for the first one, if not just change the route file as needed.

Change this

```
get 'handm/home'
```

to this

```
root 'handm#home'
```

Make sure to push to git and then deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Ok, great I have made some progress. making the change you suggested resulted in the home page showing up in the web browser. However there are 2 minor things. firstly the other pages are not showing when clicked. It simply goes to an error page stating that this page does not exist. secondly the website address is the one generated by Heroku. I have purchased a domain name and wan tot find a way to convert it. thanks.

Comment: click check mark under the number in top left corner of my answer